# Deep concatenation of nested array object values using Lodash

Tags: arrays, nested, concatenation, lodash

I have an array of objects, and each of those objects may contain children, which is another array of the same structure. I want to concatenate values of each object into a list of strings delimited with a character.

For example:

```
var array = [{
    "text": "one",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "two",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "foo"
          },
          {
            "text": "bar"
          },
          {
            "text": "baz"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "three",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "foo"
          },
          {
            "text": "bar"
          },
          {
            "text": "baz"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}, {
    "text": "two",
    "children": [
      {
        "text": "hello",
        "children": [
          {
            "text": "world"
          },
          {
            "text": "planet"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}];
```

Would result in:

```
[
    "one two foo",
    "one two bar",
    "one two baz",
    "one three foo",
    "one three bar",
    "one three baz",
    "two hello world",
    "two hello planet"
];
```

Is there any way this can be achieved using Lodash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

```
function concatString(currentString, object) {
  let string = currentString;

  if (object.text) {
    string = string + ' ' + object.text;
  }

  if (object.children) {
    string = object.children.map(item => concatString(string, item));
  }

  return string;
}

const result = _.flattenDeep(array.map(arrayItem => concatString('', arrayItem)));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tqcj18so/1/

Comment: I accepted this answer instead as it uses Lodash as requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#map` recursively to collect the strings, and then flatten the results using `Array#concat`.

ES6:

```js
const array = [{"text":"one","children":[{"text":"two","children":[{"text":"foo"},{"text":"bar"},{"text":"baz"}]},{"text":"three","children":[{"text":"foo"},{"text":"bar"},{"text":"baz"}]}]},{"text":"two","children":[{"text":"hello","children":[{"text":"world"},{"text":"planet"}]}]}];

const collect = (arr, pre = '') => {
  return [].concat([], ...arr.map((item) => {
    const label = `${pre} ${item.text}`.trim();
  
    return item.children ? collect(item.children, label) : label;
  }));
}

const result = collect(array);

console.log(result);
```

ES5:

```js
var array = [{"text":"one","children":[{"text":"two","children":[{"text":"foo"},{"text":"bar"},{"text":"baz"}]},{"text":"three","children":[{"text":"foo"},{"text":"bar"},{"text":"baz"}]}]},{"text":"two","children":[{"text":"hello","children":[{"text":"world"},{"text":"planet"}]}]}];

function collect (arr, pre) {
  return [].concat.apply([], arr.map(function(item) {
    var label = (pre + ' ' + item.text).trim();
  
    return item.children ? collect(item.children, label) : label;
  }));
}

var result = collect(array, '');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Ah, so there's no way to achieve this directly in Lodash? This works better than what I had already, and it's a lot smaller. Thanks!

Comment: @BeautifulChaos - lodash doesn't contain any method to recursively combine properties as far as I know. Welcome :)